Has it been proven that $x^6+y^6≠z^6+ w^6$, when all variables are distinct primes?
I was told that R. Balasubramanian and N. D. Hegde in 1986 proved $x^6+ y^6≠z^6 + w^6$ for distinct primes, but I couldn't find any literature.
Before I continue, I will say that all variables are distinct primes.
This is what I really needed to prove a special case of $$a^6 + b^6 + c^6≠d^6 + e^6 + f^6$$
Since $x^6+ y^6≠z^6 + w^6$, I could argue that since all variables are distinct and that $x^6 + y^6$ and $z^6 + w^6$ never equal.
Then the sums on both sides of equation will never equal. Only if $a^6$ is distinct from $b^6$.
$$a^6 + x^6 + y^6≠ b^6+ z^6+ w^6$$
Is my reasoning correct under the assumption that $x^6 + y^6≠z^6 + w^6$, and is $x^6+y^6≠z^6 + w^6$ really true for distinct primes?

Your reasoning is not correct, you cannot prove the general case so easily from the special case. You cannot add inequalities like that. Say, if $a^6 + x^6 + y^6= b^6+ z^6+ w^6$ were to hold for distinct primes, then this would immediately imply $x^6 + y^6 \neq z^6+ w^6$ since $a$ and $b$ are distinct, so the special case does not really help you. If your way of reasoning worked, you could also easily prove the special case in the same manner: $$x^6 \neq z^6 \implies x^6 + y^6 \neq z^6+ w^6$$

I also want to stress that I just used the phrase "special case" to refer to the inequality $x^6 + y^6 \neq z^6+ w^6$ for distinct primes, as you shared it. But the two inequalities that you are interested in are not a "special" and a "general" case, at least not in an obvious way. I don't see how you would prove the "special" case from the "general" case.

$a^6+b^6+c^6=d^6+e^6+f^6$ has lots of (nontrivial) integer solutions, papers by Bremner and others, though I don't know whether it has solutions in primes.

Newton, Alexis, and Jeremy Rouse. “Integers That Are Sums of Two Rational Sixth Powers.” Canadian Mathematical Bulletin 66, no. 1 (2023): 166–77. https://doi.org/10.4153/S0008439522000157 say It seems likely that no positive integer can be written as a sum of two rational sixth powers in more than one way. Ekl searched for integer solutions to  $^6+^6=^6+^6$ with  $a\ne c$ and  $a\ne d$ and found none for which  $^6+^6<7.25\times10^{24}$. The reference is Ekl, R. L., Equal sums of four seventh powers . Math. Comp. 65(1996), no. 216, 1755–1756.
.

It would not be inappropriate to ask this question on MathOverflow, provided that you include a link to the other question at each of the two sites.

Question now posted to MO, but without the requisite links on either site. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/468737/could-i-possibly-exploit-distinct-odd-primes-raised-to-6-to-solve-exact-three-co

@GerryMyerson Because this a different problem that overlaps the same problem.

In the interests of transparency, when two questions are closely related, you link them.

https://mathoverflow.net/q/468737/37212, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/54157/5038
